# How to tell failed method call parameter values?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a `List<Task<searchDataResponse>>` that contains about 30 entries.  When debugging this List I cannot determine which of the 30 entries is a specific entry.

How do I determine the method call (including input parameter value) of a specific task within a collection of tasks?

Example code:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<searchDataResponse>>();

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    // GET DATE OF N DAYS PAST (UP TO 30)
    var searchDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -1);

    // CALL WEB SERVICE WITH A SPECIFIC DATE
    var dateSpecificTask = wsClient.searchDataAsync(searchDate);

    // ADD TASK TO LIST OF TASKS
    tasks.Add(dateSpecificTask);
}

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // SET ALL EXCEPTIONS AS HANDLED
    ae.Handle(x => { return true; }); 
}

// GET LIST OF FAILED TASKS
var failedTasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted).ToList();

// IDENTIFY FAILED TASKS - TRY TO IDENTIFY WHICH DATE SUPPLIED TO WEB SERVICE FAILED.
foreach (var failedTask in failedTasks)
{
    var failedMethod = failedTask.MethodSignature;   //<----  here is what i want to do.  Property 'MethodSignature' does not exist - this is merely an example of what I am attempting to do.
}
```

**UPDATE -** 
Some of the comments suggest people having heartburn over the use of the phrase Method Signature.  What I mean by method signature is actually method signature including input parameter values.  As such I have altered the question title to reflect more accurately what I am seeking.  My example it contrived and simple.  It does not reflect my real-world problem.  But my question remains - when viewing the list of failed tasks how do I determine the actual method invoked as part of the task.  I cannot seem to find any properties of the task that describe what method caused the failure.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The phrase "method signature" has a very specific meaning in the context of C#, and in your code example you have only one "method signature", i.e. your call to `wsClient.searchDataAsync()`, which all of your tasks use. If you just want to know which tasks failed, you can simply iterate the list with an index, and use that index to recompute the data passed to the task; or even better, store that data in another list so you can correlate it. What is it _specifically_ that you're having trouble with? What do you really mean by "method signature"?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - in the example code I call the web method 30 times, each with a slightly different date.  Some of these calls will fail.  I am seeking help determining which dates were problematic calling the web service method.  When I view the collection of tasks I can see which tasks failed, but I cannot correlate to the dates.  You suggest having another list to correlate.  Would this be based on position within the list?  In otherwords, if task number 3 failed, then date in item 3 in the correlation list is the failed date?

Comment: _"Would this be based on position within the list?"_ -- yes, of course it would. That's why you'd iterate the list with an index (as I mentioned above). FYI: you are not doing yourself any favors by using the insulting and inflammatory phrase "having heartburn" to describe a legitimate concern about your misuse of technical terminology.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I guess that means there is no way to reflect the list of failed tasks to determine what actually failed?

Comment: The parameter passed to the method (to _any_ method) exists only for the duration of the call to the method. There's no way to recover it after the fact, unless you have explicitly stored it somewhere.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Thanks - I guess that's the take-away here - the list of tasks is not the task itself, but the result of the task.  Sorry for being dense -  I do appreciate the help and guidance.  With a object called Task I would expect the definition of the task to be included, rather it only holds the result of the task.

Comment: _"the list of tasks is not the task itself, but the result of the task"_ -- that's simply wrong. The list of task _does_ contain the tasks themselves. But the task is a representation of the work and a promise to deliver a result in the future. It is _not_ the method call. Once you've called a method, the call is over. The parameter you passed no longer exists. It's simply gone. Computers would collapse under their own weight if they had to keep every value that was every used during the execution of the entire program.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - trying to grok TAP - just starting my journey... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var operations = Enumerable.Range(0, 30)
 .Select(i => {
     // GET DATE OF N DAYS PAST (UP TO 30)
    var searchDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -1);

    // CALL WEB SERVICE WITH A SPECIFIC DATE
    var dateSpecificTask = wsClient.searchDataAsync(searchDate);

    return new { i, searchDate, dateSpecificTask };
}.ToList();

Task.WaitAll(operations.ConvertAll(x => x.dateSpecificTask));

var failed = operation.Where(x => x.dateSpecificTask.State == Faulted).ToList();
```

And in the `failed` list you now have all dates and indexes.

Comment: Thanks usr - again it seems all responses indicate there is no way to interrogate a Task object for its original method including parameters.  Your code illustrates a work around, where the relevant data elements are packaged up with the task object allowing a correlation between the two.  I will move forward with this strategy - thanks for the example!

Comment: A task does not have parameters. You're passing it a lambda. The parameters are packaged inside of it, inaccessible. This is a good thing. They're encapsulated. So we need to channel the state around the task.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts.  I would think that a read-only property exposing the lambda/delegate would have been helpful.  Perhaps others feel this is too much of a security vulnerability.  I dunno.  Your solution will work perfectly.

Comment: @barrypicker: there's no "lambda/delegate" in your example. You are just calling a method directly. Even if there were a delegate (e.g. passed to `Task.Run()`), that itself is just a method parameter which, again, exists only long enough to call the method. 99.99% of the time, no one ever needs to access the delegate. In _some_ cases, it would theoretically be possible to recover a parameter passed to an _inner_ method call of an anonymous method, but a) getting that would be a pain and b) that applies only to captured variables. There's no _general_ way to address the scenario.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - thanks for the input.  I believe the example supplied by @@usr will work perfectly.  Just need a way to report the failed calls, not at the task level, but rather at the business object level.  Knowing something failed but not knowing *what* failed is not helpful to my needs.  I need to address the complexities associated with one failure of many concurrent processes.  This is a complex topic and I have tried to simplify the question best I know how.  Not sure how else to ask the question of how to determine what business process did not complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to get the date passed to a task that failed, you could store the date and the task in your collection (and not only the task as you do now).

Why are you not using a intermediate class for example with two members (date, task) ?

Answer (score 1):

In the code posted by you, I find couple of discrepancies, which in my view are rooted from the fact that use of `Async-Await` is not well understood, let me bring out couple of important aspects, before suggesting an alternate solution:

Call to `wsClient.searchDataAsync(searchDate)` is not `awaited`, which defeats the purpose of an `Async` call, since that will make it a blocking `Synchronous` call, though you are aggregating all the `Async` calls in a `Task List` to wait upon later, but that is still blocking and doesn't free up the Calling thread

Code modification:

1. `await` the `wsClient.searchDataAsync` Async call, which surely needs to be part of the `async` method

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
     // GET DATE OF N DAYS PAST (UP TO 30)
       var searchDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -1);

    // CALL WEB SERVICE WITH A SPECIFIC DATE
     var dateSpecificTask = await wsClient.searchDataAsync(searchDate);

   // ADD TASK TO LIST OF TASKS
     tasks.Add(dateSpecificTask);
   }
   ```
2. Await the Task collection `Task.WhenAll` not `WaitAll`, since except console application where there's no Ui context, `WaitAll` has a scope of deadlock

Modify the code as follows:

`return await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` return value would be `Task<searchDataResponse[]>`, since all the calls have same return type `searchDataResponse`

3. Now the crux of your question, how to get the failed Tasks, though as done in the accepted in the question above, you may create a wrapper containing Task and other values and thus map them, but why not add all the relevant details in the `searchDataResponse` return type, whose schema you haven't posted, is the failure status can be added and updated in the same then from the `Task<searchDataResponse[]>` returned from the `Async` method and all that you need is:

Unwrap the result `Task<searchDataResponse[]>`, get `searchDataResponse[]` and you can have all the fail / pass details.

To Unwrap there are multiple ways for a ASP.Net project:

- Make the complete call chain `Async` and it will automatically unwrap the finally unwrap the result in the top most caller

For console application use something like:

```
searchDataResponse [] results = Task.WhenAll(<returned searchDataResponse taskList>).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Yes, the details surrounding Async-await are not well understood by me - the reason for my question.  I appreciate your input.  Thanks for clarifying Task.WaitAll vs. Task.WhenAll.  I want to use the proper tools but do not know the differences, so these details are especially helpful.  Also, its obvious you understand my objective and do not get hung-up on the semantics of my word choices.  You are correct, I didn't include the schema for searchDataResponse - trying to keep the question succinct.  I cannot modify the return type as this is a vendor supplied web service.

Comment: In that case the only option you have is the accepted solution, where via wrapper you come to know about the failed Tasks, but still keep using `Task.WhenAll`, which is much better than `Task.WaitAll` for he Async design